# WPF : Accessing themes and images from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a file for applying styles to all controls ApplicationTheme.xaml and images in Images folder.
The build action is set to resource and copy to output directory always.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/ApplicationTheme.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now similarly i give the image source in the application theme file

```
ImageSource="Images\SGL-BG.jpg"
```

However i am getting error message

```
"'Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text 'Images\\SGL-BG.jpg'.'
```

What am i doing wrong here ? This is the approach i see mentioned on websites. Also if i give the full path it works. It fails to detect the theme file as well when i give Theme/ApplicationTheme.xaml. I am a WPF noob and i am not able to find solution to this seemingly simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Source="/MyProject;component/Images/SGL-BG.jpg"
```